# Facebook Graph Feed documentation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Where can I find the documentation (parameters that can be given) of the following graph url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<PAGENAME>/feed
```

I've been searching for hours, but I can't find them.. I'm looking for the parameter to get posts till a certain date..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Time-based Pagination](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/)  to navigate through results data using Unix timestamps which point to specific times in a list of data. You can use the `until` field which as per documentation is

> A Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the end of the range of time-based data.

For example, following will give you the posts of User until 10th June 2013

```
me/feed?until=1370840400
```

Comment: That is indeed what I'm looking for, I would never come up with a search for 'Time-based Pagination'.. Anyway, you just made my day! Thanks!

Comment: I really have to look more carefully to the console log. The cursor pagination links where in there all the time!